# Problems with data persistence in the state and token loss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jwt, local-storage

I am trying to privatize some routes with JWT, everything is fine when logging in the data is saved in the state of AuthProvider as it corresponds as well as the token but when I reload the page the data is saved in a "subfield" of the state and the user token is lost somehow. This causes me problems because when the page is reloaded it redirects to the login again (public path) which is correct as long as the user is not logged in.

AuthProvider

```
import { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import clientAxios from "../config/ClientAxios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const authUser = async () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      
      if (!token) {
    
        
        return;
      }
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      };
      try {
        const data = await clientAxios("/usuarios/perfil", config);
        setAuth(data);
        navigate('/inicio')
        
      } catch (error) {
        
        setAuth({});
      }
    };

    authUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        auth,
        setAuth,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
export { AuthProvider };

export default AuthContext;
```

ProtectedRoute

```
import React from "react";
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";
import Header from "../components/Header";

const ProtectedRoute = () => {

  const { auth } = useAuth();

  return(
    <div>
      
       {auth._id ? (
        <div className="bg-gray-100">
          <Header/>
          <div className="md:min-h-screen">
            <main>
             <Outlet/>
            </main>
            
          </div>
        </div>
       )
       :<Navigate to="/"/> }
      
    </div>
  ) 
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

useAuth

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthProvider";

const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

export default useAuth;
```

Login

```
    import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import Alert from "../components/Alert";
import clientAxios from "../config/ClientAxios";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";
import { AuthProvider } from "../context/AuthProvider";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({});

  const {setAuth}=useAuth()


  const navigate=useNavigate()

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ([email, password].includes("")) {
      setAlert({
        msg: "Hay uno o mas campos vacios",
        error: true,
      });
      return;
    
    }
    try {
      const {data}=await clientAxios.post('/usuarios/',{email,password})
      setAlert({})
      localStorage.setItem('token',data.token)
      setAuth(data)
      navigate('/inicio')
    } catch (error) {
      setAlert({
        msg:error.response.data.msg,
        error:true
      })
    }
  };

  const { msg } = alert;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-sky-600 font-black text-4xl capitalize mt-3">
        Bienvenido de vuelta !
      </h1>
      <h3 className="text-gray-400 text-xl font-black">
        {" "}
        Inicia sesion y mejora tu
        <span className="text-sky-500"> ambiente laboral</span>
      </h3>

      {msg && <Alert alert={alert} />}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="my-5">
        <label
          htmlFor="email"
          className=" font-bold uppercase block text-xl text-gray-600"
        >
          Email
        </label>
        <input
          id="email"
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Email Laboral"
          className="w-full mt-3 p-3 border rounded-xl bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer"
        />
        <label
          htmlFor="password"
          className=" font-bold uppercase block text-xl text-gray-600 mt-3"
        >
          Contraseña
        </label>
        <input
          id="password"
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Contraseña"
          className="w-full mt-3 p-3 border rounded-xl bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer"
        />

        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Iniciar Sesion"
          className="bg-sky-700 text-white w-full py-3 mt-5 font-bold rounded-md uppercase hover:cursor-pointer hover:bg-sky-900 transition-colors"
        />
      </form>
      <nav>
        <Link
          className="hover:underline block text-center my-5 text-slate-500 font-semibold uppercase text-sm"
          to="forget-password"
        >
          Cambia tu Contraseña
        </Link>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

[This is what should persist even when you reload the page. This happens every time you login.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwlSm.png)

[This happens when I reload the page and it returns me to my Login. It does not help me to save the data in the State's data hood because I can not access and verify from ProtectedRoute that there is an id because it verifies directly from the State.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPyer.png)

The normal flow should be that when the page is reloaded the user's data is not lost, nor the token, since this is necessary to perform other actions within the other private routes.

Comment: You don't show where you put the token in localStorage. *Are* you putting the token in?

Comment: Yes, in my Login I set the token in local storage. I will edit it in the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your protected routes need to know if you are still loading your auth, you can try something like

```
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // start of with loading as true
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const authUser = async () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      
      if (!token) {
        setIsLoading(false); // set to false on early exit

        return;
      }

      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      };

      try {
        const { data } = await clientAxios("/usuarios/perfil", config); // destructure data from response
        setAuth(data);
        navigate('/inicio')
        
      } catch (error) {
        
        setAuth({});
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false); // set isLoading to false after your async logic is done
      }
    };

    authUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        auth,
        setAuth,
        isLoading,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {

  const { auth, isLoading } = useAuth();
  
  if (isLoading) { // don't do any redirects while loading, just wait
    return <div>authenticating...</div>;
  }

  return(
    <div>
      
       {auth._id ? (
        <div className="bg-gray-100">
          <Header/>
          <div className="md:min-h-screen">
            <main>
             <Outlet/>
            </main>
            
          </div>
        </div>
       )
       :<Navigate to="/"/> }
      
    </div>
  ) 
};
```

Comment: when I reload my AuthProvider for a moment it shows "authenticating..." then it redirects me back to Login

Comment: Could you log out `auth` in `ProtectedRoute` and see what you're getting? EDIT: I think I see the issue, updated code, neede to destructre `data`: `const data = ... -> const { data } = ...`

Comment: YEESS, I solved it, it was that and some other modifications. thank you.